# CSS: When content expands I need content below it pushed down

Tags: css, hover

Hey everyone first time posting so sorry if my format is a little off.
It took me a while but I finally found out how to cause a rollover of an image to cause my article to pop up under the picture. But the only I'm having now when when I roll over the image causing the article to appear below it, it doesn't affects the position of the images below it.

HTML

```
 <div class="postBlock">
  <img src="#.jpg" />
    <article>
      <h2>Check the mountains, nice.</h2>   
         <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Tex
          </p>
     </article>
</div>
<div class="postBlock">
  <img src="#.jpg" />
    <article>
      <h2>Check the mountains, nice.</h2>   
         <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Tex
          </p>
     </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.postBlock {
position:relative;
width:250px;
height:250px;
margin:10px;
float:left;
font-family:"Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";
border:5px solid #353432;
}
.postBlock img {
position:relative;
height:250px;
width:250px;
}
.postBlock article {
display:none;
}
.postBlock img:hover ~ article {
position:relative;
display:block;
}
.postBlock h2 {
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

So recap.
When I hover over the image box I want an article to roll out and move the image box below it down so that way you can read the article. CSS hopefully but if Javascript is needed just please explain it :) Thank you.

Here is a fiddle of it.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheDrifter/7P5RP/1/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the height value from your `.postBlock` div and you're fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7P5RP/2/

Or if you wish, you can use `min-height` instead of `height`. The important thing is to allow the div to expand vertically.

---

Here is a nicer solution, I've moved the borders to the images, not the containers, I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7P5RP/3/

Comment: Geez, I feel dumb. lol Well that does fix the problem I presented but, sorry there is always a but.

one the one on my computer I am using float:left because I have three of those post blocks per line and when I hover over a image it drops down the article but it clears the entire line below it and not just enough space for the article. I have a feeling I am going to need JS to do what I want. Any help would be great though thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you recreate that version you have in jsfiddle?

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheDrifter/7P5RP/)!

If you expand window so that it has three boxes up top and one below you can see the issue I am talking about, when it is two boxes on top and you hover of the first box then it is okay but then as you hover over 2nd box it causes the entire row to drop. Thanks again.

Comment: If you know how many columns you'll have, you can put each row into a separate container and it should work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/7P5RP/8/ ... Note, I've also added the clear divs (clear:both).

Comment: That is what I will do then, cause I am going to have 3 boxes per row so I will just use three columns. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's what's generally good to do, because floated elements are hard to control unless contained. You're welcome!